# Problem with using inner-join to merge two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have the following code below:

```
universitytowns = pd.merge(houses,unitowns,how='inner',on=['State','RegionName'])
```

However, my output is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [State, RegionName, 2000q1, 2000q2, 2000q3, 2000q4, 2001q1, 2001q2, 2001q3, 2001q4, 2002q1, 2002q2, 2002q3, 2002q4, 2003q1, 2003q2, 2003q3, 2003q4, 2004q1, 2004q2, 2004q3, 2004q4, 2005q1, 2005q2, 2005q3, 2005q4, 2006q1, 2006q2, 2006q3, 2006q4, 2007q1, 2007q2, 2007q3, 2007q4, 2008q1, 2008q2, 2008q3, 2008q4, 2009q1, 2009q2, 2009q3, 2009q4, 2010q1, 2010q2, 2010q3, 2010q4, 2011q1, 2011q2, 2011q3, 2011q4, 2012q1, 2012q2, 2012q3, 2012q4, 2013q1, 2013q2, 2013q3, 2013q4, 2014q1, 2014q2, 2014q3, 2014q4, 2015q1, 2015q2, 2015q3, 2015q4, 2016q1, 2016q2, 2016q3, difference]
Index: []

[0 rows x 70 columns]
```

I am confused as to why this is...

The dataframe **houses** looks like this:

```
State    RegionName         2000q1         2000q2         2000q3  \
0      New York      New York            NaN            NaN            NaN   
1    California   Los Angeles  207066.666667  214466.666667  220966.666667   
2      Illinois       Chicago  138400.000000  143633.333333  147866.666667   
3  Pennsylvania  Philadelphia   53000.000000   53633.333333   54133.333333   
4       Arizona       Phoenix  111833.333333  114366.666667  116000.000000   

          2000q4         2001q1         2001q2         2001q3         2001q4  \
0            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
1  226166.666667  233000.000000  239100.000000  245066.666667  253033.333333   
2  152133.333333  156933.333333  161800.000000  166400.000000  170433.333333   
3   54700.000000   55333.333333   55533.333333   56266.666667   57533.333333   
4  117400.000000  119600.000000  121566.666667  122700.000000  124300.000000   

       ...              2014q3         2014q4         2015q1         2015q2  \
0      ...       522800.000000  528066.666667  532266.666667  540800.000000   
1      ...       509066.666667  518866.666667  528800.000000  538166.666667   
2      ...       195766.666667  201266.666667  201066.666667  206033.333333   
3      ...       115300.000000  115666.666667  116200.000000  117966.666667   
4      ...       165366.666667  168500.000000  171533.333333  174166.666667   

          2015q3         2015q4         2016q1         2016q2    2016q3  \
0  557200.000000  572833.333333  582866.666667  591633.333333  587200.0   
1  547266.666667  557733.333333  566033.333333  577466.666667  584050.0   
2  208300.000000  207900.000000  206066.666667  208200.000000  212000.0   
3  121233.333333  122200.000000  123433.333333  126933.333333  128700.0   
4  179066.666667  183833.333333  187900.000000  191433.333333  195200.0   

     difference  
0  33933.333333  
1  55600.000000  
2  12300.000000  
3    766.666667  
4  25533.333333
```

The dataframe **unitowns** looks like this:

```
[5 rows x 70 columns]
     State     RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn 
1  Alabama      Florence 
2  Alabama  Jacksonville 
3  Alabama    Livingston 
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @ggorlen to have all the contents of the columns State and RegionName from the unitowns dataframe, and the remaining contents from the Houses dataframe. Thus, there should be 517 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me. Are you sure the 2 dataframes have a common `state` and `RegionName`. I just modified the `unitowns` dataframe to include New York and New York and it worked, or there might be some extra characters, space, etc.

```
universitytowns = pd.merge(houses,unitowns,how='inner',on=['State','RegionName'])
print(universitytowns)

      State RegionName  2000q1  2000q2  2000q3
0  New York   New York     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: When you say extra characters/space, I need to use the str.strip() function for that, would I do houses['State'].str.strip() and houses['RegionName'].str.strip() and same for unitowns

Comment: State                     RegionName
0          Alabama                        Auburn 
1          Alabama                      Florence 
2          Alabama                  Jacksonville 
3          Alabama                    Livingston 
4          Alabama                    Montevallo 
5          Alabama                          Troy 
6          Alabama                    Tuscaloosa 
7          Alabama                      Tuskegee 
8           Alaska                     Fairbanks  

for unitowns

Comment: State           RegionName        2000q1        2000q2  \
0                  New York             New York           NaN           NaN   
1                California          Los Angeles  2.070667e+05  2.144667e+05   
2                  Illinois              Chicago  1.384000e+05  1.436333e+05   
3              Pennsylvania         Philadelphia  5.300000e+04  5.363333e

This is for Houses

Comment: Have tried this: 
houses = houses.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
unitowns = unitowns.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
Has not sovled the issue, still an empty data frame